# How to fix Apache Server child pid 637 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2 Issue

Tags: apache, server, apache2, lamp

I am facing apache server issue. I have check apache server logs and seems likes its go in infinate loop. error log continuously display below errors.

```
 [Fri Mar 15 04:39:52.384115 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1413 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:52.384174 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1413
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385026 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1416 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385106 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1416
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385122 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1417 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385126 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1417
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385137 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1418 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385141 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1418
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385152 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1419 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:53.385156 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1419
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:55.390520 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30896] AH00051: child pid 1426 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:55.390821 2019] [core:error] [pid 30896] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 1426
```

When I restart apache server Site is working.

Anyone please suggest solution to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I gout the same problem with Ubuntu 19.04, opened a ticked at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1821293

Comment: Hello @caiofior Did you get any solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: Dear @rigal , no solution has been found, the problem appears only once a week and log files do not preset any clue